# Find Text Value of closest first p using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple columns like this

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <div class="blog_content d-flex bg-dark text-white flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
            <h5 class="mb-0 border-0">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત </h5>
            <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 h-100">
                <div class="flip-card h-100">
                    <div class="flip-card-inner h-100">
                        <div class="flip-card-front d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br> શુભકામનાઓ !!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flip-card-back d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">nutan varsh 2023 ni<br> sharuat kaik evi thay,<br> tamar jivanam khushio felay,<br> anand mangalathi darek divas<br> pasar thay evi hardik<br> shubhakamanao !!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto pt-3">
                <div class="left text-start">
                    <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a></h6>
                    <p class="mb-0"><small>1 day ago</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <span class="copy"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/copy.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></span>
                    <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/share.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I am looking for is get value of nearest p text inside flip-card-front class when I click copy class image icon. I am new in javascript and does not getting idea how I can do it.

```
var copy = document.getElementsByClassName('copy');
            for (var i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
              copy[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                //get text   નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br> શુભકામનાઓ !!
        console.log("p tag value which is inside flip-card-front");
              });
            }
```

I am trying from last hour but have not found any working solution for achieve my goal. Let me know if someone here can help me for same. Thanks!

Comment: So, you click on `flip-card-ront` and you need text of `p` tag in it? Am I correct?

Comment: @Rajesh copy is my button and on click it, I want get text value for <p> element which is inside flip-card-front class div.

Comment: _"I am trying from last hour..."_ - There's nothing in your question -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve], [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding your structure

you search closest blog_content, from there search flip-card-front p:

```js
copy[i].addEventListener('click', evt => {
   const el = evt.target.closest('.blog_content');
   const mySearchedText = el.querySelector('.flip-card-front p).innerHTML;
});
```

not tested but should be ok

Answer (score 1):

You you need to do:

- Navigate to the necessary node.
- For this, you will have to go to common parent in the DOM tree. You can use `.closest` to do that.
- Once you have parent, you can lookup any necessary element from it

```js
var copy = document.getElementsByClassName('copy');
for (var i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
  copy[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const content = this.closest('.blog_content')
    const cardFront = content.querySelector('.flip-card-front p')
    const text = cardFront.textContent;
    console.log(text)
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
  <div class="blog_content d-flex bg-dark text-white flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
    <h5 class="mb-0 border-0">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત </h5>
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 h-100">
      <div class="flip-card h-100">
        <div class="flip-card-inner h-100">
          <div class="flip-card-front d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <p class="">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br> શુભકામનાઓ !!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <p class="">nutan varsh 2023 ni<br> sharuat kaik evi thay,<br> tamar jivanam khushio felay,<br> anand mangalathi darek divas<br> pasar thay evi hardik<br> shubhakamanao !!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto pt-3">
      <div class="left text-start">
        <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a></h6>
        <p class="mb-0"><small>1 day ago</small></p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <span class="copy"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/copy.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></span>
        <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/share.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working like expected. I have up voted your answer. Thanks a lot